# How to properly draw layout with image and add text to it

Tags: android, layout

I have created a grid view in Android. Now I want to use this custom layout to put text in the view. I can work on all views, but how can I create the view shown in picture and add text in the white space of image and inside blue rectangle too?

[image]

Comment: Share your code.
What you tried in xml code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try framelayout. I have tried one for you. Feel free to ask if you are not getting something.

```
  <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/imageViewCircle"
                    android:layout_width="100dp"
                    android:layout_height="100dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/mypng" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textView"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
                    android:gravity="center|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="50"
                    android:textSize="40sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/textViewNumeric"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                    android:gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                    android:text="Text"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"
                    android:textSize="20sp"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </FrameLayout>
```

Comment: man you made exact how I wanted. But I needed image without those text. No matter other users can remove text their with photoshop or inkscape.